# White borders around div tag when surrounded by an anchor

Tags: css, joomla, google-chrome

I've been experiencing a strange issue.

I've made these buttons using div tags, they have rounded edges and the color of their borders is defined in CSS. To make them point to somewhere I surrounded them with `<a>` tags. The problem is, when the link points to something previously visited, the divs border turns white. Normally, I'd just inspect the element in Chrome to see which CSS rule does that but as soon as I navigate to that element, the border fixes itself to the color it's supposed to be.

This happens in Chrome but not in IE or Firefox.

Also, I'm using Joomla 1.5 and Artisteer to make the template (although I did modify it a lot).

As a temporary solution I used onclick JavaScript linkage to make the button work but I don't think that would go too well with search engine crawlers.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you supply a screenshot? Is it the `div` border, or a focus outline?

Comment: @TimMedora that was last century in HTML 4.01. HTML5 allows `div` elements inside an `a`.

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools (F12) to inspect the `div` and the parent `a` to check for any offending margin on the `div` or padding on the `a`.

Comment: So what did people do before they could do that?

Comment: @Darwin, the web was a much duller place back then.

Comment: @Strelok - hardly last century, but you are right so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Darwin - `display: inline-block` or `display: block` will provide a similar effect.

Comment: @TimMedora in last century in internet years :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome developer tool you have options to view elements on hover etc. If you haven't assigned styles for a:active, a:visited etc you should. If you'd like more help please post your code into jsfiddle

Comment: The problem is that if you want to view the style of the element you have to click the element. It then magically fixes itself.
Also, here's the fiddle but it's not going to help because it works properly when outside of my site: http://jsfiddle.net/xAGr9/

Comment: Have you set styles for all pseudo classes? a:link, a:visited, a:hover, and a:active? In jsfiddle you should link all your javascript and CSS in the left side menu click Add Resources so that we can see if it's your CSS or JS files messing with the link style

Comment: But it's Joomla. I can't possibly link all CSS files. Or if you really think it'll help I'll try. And yes, I did define all those.

Comment: @Darwin right click on some parent element of the `a` and inspect that. Then find the `a` in the DOM tree that appears in Chrome Dev Tools. You can also click the little icon in Chrome Dev Tools that looks like a dotted rectangle with an arrow (it's in the "Styles" section on the right) to toggle different element states without touching the actual element. Is your site live? Can we have a look?

Comment: Well, what's the harm in showing it. http://elopakao.com/ You can see the buttons bellow the slideshow. The first one is using JavaScript for linking and it's fine, the second one uses anchor and it has a white border (make sure you click on it and then go back to the homepage since it only does that if the page is visited)

Comment: Also, I don't think it's the anchor that's getting the border but the div itself. I can navigate to the <a> tag and look through it's style and is says nothing about white borders but when I go inside it and click the div tag, the border disappears.